# java - Get and Set value in a map of list

Tags: java, list, dictionary

how can I retrieve a value from a list inserted into a list in map?
I have my main class

```
public class Path {
private Map<Integer, List<Arc>> mapNode;
private final Arc arc;

public Path() {
    this.arc = new Arc();

    double coll[][] = {{1, 13}, {2, 21}, {21, 2}, {7, 21}, {21, 5}};

    mapNode = new HashMap();

    for (int i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        if (!mapNode.containsKey((int) coll[i][0])) {
            mapNode.put((int) coll[i][0], new ArrayList());
        }
        Arc arc = new Arc();
        arc.setOrigin((int) coll[i][0]);
        arc.setDestination((int) coll[i][1]);

        mapNode.get(arc.getOrigin()).add(arc);
                mapNode.get(arc.getOrigin()).get(arc.getDestination()).getOccupancy().setInit(0);

    }
}
}
```

Into my map, I have a list of Arc. It contains origin, destination and also a list of occupancy:

```
public class Arc {

private int origin;
private int destination;

private Occupancy occupancy;
private List <Occupancy> time_occupancy;
public Arc(){
}

public Arc(int origin, int destination){
    this.origin = origin;
    this.destination = destination;
}

public Occupancy getOccupancy() {
    return occupancy;
}

public void setOccupancy(Occupancy occupancy) {
    this.occupancy = occupancy;
}

public List<Occupancy> getTime_occupancy() {
    return time_occupancy;
}

public void setTime_occupancy(List<Occupancy> time_occupancy) {
    this.time_occupancy = time_occupancy;
}

public int getOrigin() {
    return origin;
}

public void setOrigin(int origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
}

public int getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(int destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}
}
```

Occupancy is the time when the arc is not available, it has two variables: `init` and `end`.

```
class Occupancy {
double init;
double end;

public Occupancy(double init, double end){
    this.init = init;
    this.end = end;
}

public double getInit() {
    return init;
}

public void setInit(double init) {
    this.init = init;
}

public double getEnd() {
    return end;
}

public void setEnd(double end) {
    this.end = end;
}
```

}

I cant's store value in my list of occupancy. I tried:

```
mapNode.get(arc.getOrigin()).get(arc.getDestination()).getOccupancy().setInit(0);
```

but it doesn't work. I can get and set value in my list of arc but I can't use my list of occupancy.

Comment: For example: I have my list of arcs, I'd like to store the time of occupancy of arc which has origin=1 and destination=13. I want to setInit=0 and setEnd=4. Then setInit=5 and setEnd=9...using "mapNode.get(arc.getOrigin()).get(arc.getDestination()).getOccupancy().setInit(0);" it says: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Initialize generics like so:

```
private Map<Integer, List<Arc>> mapNode;
private final Arc arc;

public Path() {
    this.arc = new Arc();

    double coll[][] = {{1, 13}, {2, 21}, {21, 2}, {7, 21}, {21, 5}};

    mapNode = new HashMap<Integer, List<Arc>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        if (!mapNode.containsKey((int) coll[i][0])) {
            mapNode.put((int) coll[i][0], new ArrayList<Arc>());
        }
```

Afterwards, you can easily index and get TYPED items rather than having to cast objects.

Of course, you'd get lists and items from lists like this:

```
   Map<Integer, List<Arc>> mapNode = ...;
   ...
   List<Arc> list = mapNode.get(5); //example Integer
   Arc arc = list.get(0); //index of 0
```